# How to measure network traffic (with pfSense/freeBSD)?

Tags: networking, freebsd, traffic, pfsense

Is it possible to measure network traffic (per month, per WAN, per direction) with pfSense/freeBSD?

There are following programs listed https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/How_can_I_monitor_bandwidth_usage but neither seems to work normally for me. For example, `ntopng` shows only current flow while `BandwidthD` can monitor only one interface.

Shame to say, but I still don't know how many bytes I spent with each provider.

I have pfsense installed on my router computer. pfsense is based of freebsd.

Answer (score 1):

Install the "vnstat2" package under System/Packages.  Then go to Status/Vnstat2.  The summary tab will show you information like:

```
                      rx      /      tx      /     total    /   estimated
 em1:
       Jun '15     64.34 GiB  /   10.39 GiB  /   74.73 GiB  /   98.00 GiB
     yesterday      5.30 GiB  /  373.42 MiB  /    5.66 GiB
         today      2.90 GiB  /  197.29 MiB  /    3.09 GiB  /    3.52 GiB
```

You can also use "vnstat -i em1 -m" to get monthly stats for a particular interface.

(vnstat is also available for Linux, which is where I learned of it)

Answer (score 0):

[SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) is one typical way to measure network traffic.  [This page](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/book/services/snmp.html) documents some of the aspects of using SNMP in conjunction with pfSense.

I'm actually using the `bsnmpget` component of FreeBSD's `bsnmpd` SNMP implementation in this example, but most any SNMP suite will permit you to do things like:

```
$ # query the number of interfaces present:
$ bsnmpget ifNumber.0
ifNumber.0 = 6
$ for iface in $(jot $(bsnmpget -o quiet ifNumber.0))
do
     bsnmpget ifName[$iface]
     bsnmpget ifInOctets[$iface]
     bsnmpget ifOutOctets[$iface]
     printf -- '--\n'
done
ifName[1] = em0
ifInOctets[1] = 1430450040
ifOutOctets[1] = 2237124338
--
ifName[2] = lo0
ifInOctets[2] = 46500610
ifOutOctets[2] = 46500610
--
ifName[3] = public
ifInOctets[3] = 1407864504
ifOutOctets[3] = 2237124186
--
ifName[4] = vlan1
ifInOctets[4] = 6933941
ifOutOctets[4] = 0
--
ifName[5] = vlan3
ifInOctets[5] = 5776832
ifOutOctets[5] = 152
--
ifName[6] = vm-public
ifInOctets[6] = 714355313
ifOutOctets[6] = 0
--
```